# Taylor series of a complex function that is not holomorphic

Tags: taylor-series, cv.complex-variables

I want to create Taylor series of a complex function that has complex conjugate in it. Obviously I cannot do a total derivative but derivations over real and imag parts exist.

Bonus question: Can I produce a Taylor series using only derivations over real part?

Comment: Maybe there is something about Taylor series using directional derivatives instead of partial derivatives. 

Comment: The reason why I wanted to find a Taylor series was to produce a Newton method. Finally I found that I needed to look into CR Calculus http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.86.6515&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is $\sum c_{mn}z^m \bar z^n$, which still keeps track of the complex structure. For instance, harmonic functions will have $c_{mn}=0$ unless $mn=0$.

Comment: So I can always transform my complex function to f(z,z*). But how do I do a derivative of that?

Answer (score 6):

Remember that the complex plane is $\mathbb{R}^2$ and use [normal old multivariable Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables).

Comment: My function is thus R^2 to R^2 and it seems that your link is only about scalar valued multivariable function. 